# Laravel 8 API returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a simple website in Laravel and Vue, code is running in Homestead. When the user visits the home page of the website, videos are being displayed in a grid. So API is called to fetch data and the return I get is an HTML of a .view file instead of JSON.

```
// API Routes in Api.php
Route::get('/videos', [VideoController::class, 'getVideos']);
Route::get('/videos/{id}', [VideoController::class, 'getVideo']);
Route::post('/user/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/user/check', [UserController::class, 'checkUser']);
```

```
// Controller function that returns data from website via ORM
public function getVideos(): JsonResponse{
    return resonse()->json([
        "response" => Video::all()
    ]);
}
```

Response in the console I get when API is being called
[image]

Php artisan route:list
[image]

Comment: Possibly another controller is being hit, check your api call with a dd() inside it

Comment: also show your routes with php artisan route:list could help

Comment: What is inside your `api` middleware group?

Comment: I tried dd(), but it still returns HTML

Comment: I used to have something similar were the api required to be authenticated and when I wasn't it would try to redirect me. But since it's a json response it would try to render the login page in the json response instead.

Comment: what does your auth.php config says under guards

Comment: It already redirects, before even hitting the controller...and it redirects to the apparently wrong route. The middleware should return a JSON response instead, complaining that the user is not logged in.

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

Comment: Likely you'd need to present a user's API token.

Comment: Well, I just implemented the user login with JWT. The token that is received upon login is stored in local storage and sent with every API request, yet still, API returns HTML.

Comment: it would seem the request is going to the catch all route not the api routes

Comment: Hi @Liondalan , I have same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yeah, I made another project and copied everything from the previous project to the current one

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly, your response is rendering Html instead of JSON?

You can create a global JsonMiddleware that accepts headers as application/json. To do this follow the following steps:

### Step 1: create a new middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware JsonMiddleware
```

### Step 2: Copy this code and place it inside the JsonMiddleware at the handle method before 'return $next($request);'

```
$request->headers->set("Accept", "application/json");
```

#### Your end result should look like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->headers->set("Accept", "application/json");
    return $next($request);
}
```

### Step 3: Go to App\Http\Kernel.php file and add the code below at global HTTP middleware stack.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\JsonMiddleware::class,
    // Other Middleware::class comes after...
];
```

### Step 4: clear the application config cache and dump autoload

```
php artisan config:cache or composer dump-autoload
```

I hope this is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was triggered by a middleware I created to check for some user info on every refresh.

Livewire sends a request to the backend for all bound attribute changes.
The request would hit my middleware and I'd get a redirect to the target page.

In my case this only happened during onboarding cuz it's when I was checking if my user had the info.
I just prevented all livewire requests from accessing this middleware and this was sorted out.

MyMiddleware.php

```
....
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
   
  if (!str_contains($request->path(), 'livewire')) {
      // you can prevent specific routes if you wish, this is general

      if(my_condition_is_true){
          return redirect('/just/go/there')
      }
  }

   return $next($request);
}
```